# Find the pdf for the Non-central F-distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I am strugling with deriving the pdf (probability density function) for a non-central F-distribution. The pdf is of course easy to find on google and elsewhere, but deriving, looks tough.

Here is my try:

I assume $X\sim {\chi}^2(n,\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the non-centrality parameter of $X$, and let $Y\sim {\chi}^2(m)$. Then I define $Z$ such that:

$Z=\frac{X}{Y}$.

Here I have tried to divide the densities of $X$ and $Y$, but this does not give me the same as the density for $Z$, and given on the internet.

Does anybody know anything useful here?

Comment: 2 years later but... When it comes to random variables, the density of the quotient is not the quotient of the densities